# How to automatically sync updated master branch code with its sub branches?

Tags: javascript, angular, git, github, aws-amplify

I have an Angular 9 app that follows the following Github branch structure:

`develop` -> `staging` -> `master`

and

`master` can be branched into multiple `event` branches.

Here `event` branches are customer-facing with only small UI changes and **all the above branches are deployed and hosted on AWS Amplify**.

Now I'm facing difficulty in scaling my Angular application.

If the `master` branch is updated with new features or bugfix, How can I sync all `event` branches with the new code? I don't want to merge `master` with each of the `event` branches one by one. There might be 100+ `event` branches.

Comment: Would it be an option to make all these customer-facing changes configurable? Since those are - as you say - small UI changes, this could be much easier. In this case you don't need to manage this immense amount of "productive" branches. Otherwise, you could create a script that merges master into all these branches.

Comment: @Matt The Event branches share the same feature logic and the UI (background image, colour etc) can be customized through an Admin Panel. I don't understand how you're suggesting I configure it.

Comment: What exactly are the differences between the `event` branches then?

Comment: @Matt Consider `event` branches as separate Events or Conferences for each of our Client. They have their own sub-domain and have a separate database as well. Now when `master` is updated with a new feature on FE, How can I update all the other `event` branches? Can I also architect my Angular app to avoid this issue by  using `Monorepo`?